# 'He IS an alumnus' or 'He WAS an alumnus'?

Tags: word-usage

Should 'alumni' be used with past tense? Or is the past-tense built in with the word so people with a degree are always currently alumni of somewhere?

Comment: See [this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+an+alumnus%2Cwas+an+alumnus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20an%20alumnus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20an%20alumnus%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20an%20alumnus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20an%20alumnus%3B%2Cc0) It just depends on whether the alumnus in question is still alive. You can't cease to be an alumnus if you ever were one - being dead just moves your status to Past Tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is probably true for the OP's use-case, but it doesn't "just" depend on that.  For example, if you were writing a past-tense narrative (such as a typical novel) then you'd use "was" without any implications about death.

Comment: @rjpond: Hmm. I think that's just standard "backshifting", same as *Apollo 8 took nearly three days to reach the Moon, which **was** almost 1/4 million miles away*. To a first approximation, *everything* is normally in the past in a typical narrative context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, I think.  Perhaps I was being pedantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the present tense. An alumnus is a person who previously graduated from a school or university. Such a person will always be an alumnus (unless perhaps the diploma is revoked or something).

Also, note that *alumnus* is a masculine form. The corresponding feminine form is *alumna*. Plural forms are *alumni* (masculine or mixed gender / gender neutral) and the rarely-seen *alumnae* (feminine).

Comment: Past tense here usually indicates the person is dead.

Comment: There seems to be some dispute (including disagreement among dictionaries) about whether you need to graduate to be considered an alumnus.  See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49361/alumnus-vs-dropout-can-you-still-call-someone-who-chooses-to-quit-college-u

Comment: When soliciting donations, Alleyn's School considers me an 'alumnus', even though students don't 'graduate' from British secondary school. Since they went co-ed in the 1970s, they stopped calling former pupils 'old boys'.

Comment: @rjpond true: I'd guess most people think of alumni as graduates, but clearly it's sometimes used for anyone who attended. In Latin (from which alumni is taken) it simply means _student_.

Comment: This is surely picking nits, but I wouldn't call *alumnae* "rare."  In the US, at least, we still have a fair number of prominent women's colleges, so you'll see "Scripps alumnae," "Barnard alumnae," "Smith alumnae," etc.  Rar**er** to be sure.